# TestNG :: How to get TestSuite name inside a TestMethod?

Tags: java, testng, selenium-grid

I have a scenario where many test suites are added to TestNG object for running. I have a testMethod() in a class TestClass. I am using dataProvider also.

I want to know inside the test method which is the current TestSuite ??

How can I achieve without disturbing my DataProvider parameters for the TestMethod ??

Answer (score 0):

Here is the way Cedric implemented it after much convincing as you can see in [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/testng-users/jiGo3p20cnw) thread from a long time ago:

```
  @DataProvider(name = "A")
  protected Object[][] dp(ITestContext tc) {
    return new Object[][] { 
        { tc }
    };
  }

  @Test(dataProvider = "A")
  public void testA(ITestContext tc) {
    System.out.println("SUITE NAME:" + tc.getSuite().getXmlSuite().getName());
  }
```

Comment: Thanks @Vidya,
But I have a different scenario here.
My dataProvider method takes arguments like 
`dp(Method method){
    return {{myMap.get(method.getName)}};
}`

And I want not to change this logic. Can I still proceed with ITestContext and get the method name in the dataProvider method ??

Answer (score 0):

Got the Answer.

From the [book by Beust](http://testng.org/doc/book.html) I got my answer.

There are different ways to define a dataProvider method:

```
@DataProvider
public void create() { ... }
@DataProvider
public void create(Method method) { ... }
@DataProvider
public void create(ITestContext context) { ... }
@DataProvider
public void create(Method method, ITestContext context) { ... }
```

And the last method helped me solve my problem.
This method gives the method reference that is going to be called as well as the Test Context.